# ネットワーク経由でadb実行した後について

Tags: android, network

**「ネットワーク経由でadb実行」後、しばらく経って再度「ネットワーク経由でadb実行」する場合について**
・[リンク先](https://qiita.com/hamup/items/d0757af393a5462b686a)内容は、常に最初にUSB接続が必要でしょうか？
・再度USB接続が必要な要件を知りたいです

・色々試してみたのですが、「adb disconnect」後「adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx」コマンドを打つだけで繋がる場合もあるし、再度USB接続しなければつながらない場合もあり、何によって挙動が変わるのかよく分かりません

Comment: 思いつきで書きますが、WiFiがいったん切断されたか否かや、adbのセッション的なもののタイムアウト（一定時間経過）があやしいですね。

Comment: ここら辺りを具体的に確認する方法はありますか？ 「adb devices」？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ・リンク先内容は、常に最初にUSB接続が必要でしょうか？

必要です。以下の実行でUSB接続している必要があります。

```
$adb tcpip 5555
```

補足するとadb接続では端末側のadbd(daemon)とホストPC側のadbd(daemon)が存在し、通常端末側のadbd(daemon)はUSB経由でのadb接続を待ち受けています。
上記のコマンドは、ホストPC側のadbdからUSB経由で端末側のadbdにWi-Fi接続(WiFiだけとは限りませんが)での5555ポートでadb接続を待ち受けるように指示するコマンドです。

```
<ホストPC>adbd ---- USB ---> <端末>adbd
```

このコマンド実行で端末側のadbdがUSBではなくipで待ち受けるようになり、Wi-Fiでのadb接続が可能になります。
(逆にUSBからのadb接続ができなくなるはずです。端末側の実装依存にはなりますが）

---

> ・再度USB接続が必要な要件を知りたいです
>   ・色々試してみたのですが、「adb disconnect」後「adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx」コマンドを打つだけで繋がる場合もあるし、再度USB接続しなければつながらない場合もあり、何によって挙動が変わるのかよく分かりません

端末側のadbdの待ち受けがUSBになっていたらUSB接続し、上記コマンドの実行からやり直す必要があります。
「adb disconnect」「adb connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx」のコマンドはWi-Fi経由でのadbの接続/切断を指示するコマンドです。
端末側のadbdがUSBで待ち受けていたら、コマンド実行しても意味がありません。
コメントにもありますが、端末側のメーカー実装次第で再度USB接続が必要かどうかは、様々なケースがあり得るので明確な回答は難しいです。

・USB抜き差しを検知して端末側のadbdの待ち受けがUSBに変わる（かもしれない）
・ネットワークの変更を検知して端末側のadbdの待ち受けがUSBに変わる（かもしれない）
・その他何かの変化を検知して端末側のadbdの待ち受けがUSBに変わる

複合条件の可能性もありますし、必要な要件を確実に知りたいのであれば端末の製造メーカーに問い合わせた方が良いと思います。
１つだけ明確にわかる条件は端末を再起動するとadbdは初期状態のUSB待ち受けになると思います。

Comment: 再度USB接続が必要な要件は「端末側の実装に依存している」のですね。それでは素直に、最初にUSB接続した後でadb接続していきたいと思います

Answer (score 0):

Android Studioのマニュアルを読む限り、「接続が切れた後で再接続できない場合は、USB接続の手順からやり直すように」と読めます。

---

[Android Debug Bridge | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html?hl=ja)

**Wi-Fi を介した端末への接続**

adb 接続が失われた場合は、次の手順を実行します。

1. Android 端末が接続されている Wi-Fi ネットワークと同じネットワークにホストが引き続き接続されていることを確認します。
2. adb connect のステップを再度実行して再接続します。
3. 上記の手順で接続できない場合は、adb ホストをリセットします。

   ```
   adb kill-server
   ```
4. その後、最初からやり直します。